# Intent in ListActivity not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have 1 ListView and 2 buttons in layout.xml file as shown below:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBookRoomInRoomselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnBookRoomInRoomselection"
        android:width="150dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelInRoomselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnCancelInRoomselection"
        android:width="150dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my java class:

```
public class RoomSelectionActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

List<String> bookroom;
Button btnBookRoom;
Button btnCancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.roomselection);

    bookroom = new ArrayList<String>();
    //TODO change the list content from the db
    bookroom.add("Room1");
    bookroom.add("Room2");
    bookroom.add("Room3");
    bookroom.add("Room4");

    btnBookRoom = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBookRoomInRoomselection);
    btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancelInRoomselection);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            bookroom));

    btnBookRoom.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnBookRoom:

        Intent bookRoomIntent = new Intent(this,RoomBookedActivity.class);
        startActivity(bookRoomIntent);
        break;

    case R.id.btnCancel:


        break;
    }

}

}
```

When I click the `BookRoom` button, the intent is not working. I am not sure why this is not working. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Oh ok my mistake, i got the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: you missing context for start activity, try **getBaseContext()**.startActivity(bookRoomIntent); .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
case R.id.btnBookRoom
```

with

```
case R.id.btnBookRoomInRoomselection
```

Answer (score 0):

case R.id.btnBookRoomInRoomselection